# How to show the Color image feed from kinect using freenect2-python

Tags: python-imaging-library, kinect, imshow, opencv, libfreenect2, python

I'm using [freenect2-python](https://rjw57.github.io/freenect2-python/#) to read frames from kinectv2. Following is my code:

```py
from freenect2 import Device, FrameType
import cv2
import numpy as np

def callback(type_, frame):
    print(f'{type_}, {frame.format}') 
    if type_ is FrameType.Color: # FrameFormat.BGRX
        rgb = frame.to_array().astype(np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow('rgb', rgb[:,:,0:3])

device = Device()
while True:
    device.start(callback)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        device.stop()
        break
```

The color frame format is `FrameFormat.BGRX`, so I'm taking the first 3 channels to show the image. But it shows a blank black window.

[image]

I used `PIL` but it opens a new window for each frame it receives. Is there a way to show frames in the same window in `PIL`?

Answer (score 0):

The `cv2.imshow` couldn't display anything because it was continuously getting updated with a new frame. I added `cv2.waitkey(100)` after `cv2.imshow` and it worked.

```py
def callback(type_, frame):
    print(f'{type_}, {frame.format}') 
    if type_ is FrameType.Color: # FrameFormat.BGRX
        rgb = frame.to_array().astype(np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow('rgb', rgb[:,:,0:3])
        # added the following line of code
        cv2.imshow(100)
```